# opengl read .3ds file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

first I convert chesspawn.3ds file to chesspawn.gl and chesspawn.h with View3DS
second I write a opengl program to view this model.
This is the code

```
#include "stdafx.h"  
#include <gl/glut.h>  
#include <cstdlib>  
#include "chesspawn.h"
#include <gl/GL.h>

GLuint model = -1;
void display()
{
    glCallList(model);
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -10.0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(1280, 720);
    glutInitWindowPosition(150, 150);

    model = GL3DS_initialize_chesspawn();

    glutCreateWindow("TeaPot");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The key function GL3DS_initialize_chesspawn

```
  int GL3DS_initialize_chesspawn() {
    int ReturnVal;
    FILE *in;
    if (!(in = fopen("chesspawn.gl", "rb")))
      return(-1);

  if (fread(GL3DS_VERTEX_chesspawn, 33152, 1, in) != 1)
    return(-1);
  fclose(in);

    ReturnVal = glGenLists(1);
    glInterleavedArrays(GL_T2F_N3F_V3F, 0, GL3DS_VERTEX_chesspawn);
    glNewList(ReturnVal, GL_COMPILE);
     glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
     glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
     glCullFace(GL_BACK);
     glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
     glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, (GLfloat *)    &GL3DS_M ATERIAL_chesspawn[0]);
     glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, (GLfloat *) &GL3DS_MATERIAL_chesspawn[4]);
     glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, (GLfloat *) &GL3DS_MATERIAL_chesspawn[8]);
     glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6204, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &GL3DS_INDEX_chesspawn[0]);
  glEndList();
  return (ReturnVal);
}
```

Now,The Program can run successfully but I can't view the model.Just a empty screen.

Comment: @datenwolf: "*because the contents of the arrays are not actually stored in the display list*" Actually, they are. By the nature of how client-side arrays work, the data *must* have been pulled from the vertex arrays into the renderer by the time `glDrawElements` returns. Therefore, in display list form, the data *must* have been pulled into the display list when that function returns.

Comment: @NicolBolas: It's been too long since I actively used display lists, and I never mixed them with VAs. But after reading that part of the specification again (first time since some 12 years or so): Yes, you're completely right (as usual).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's GL3DS but there's something wrong in the init.

It looks like GL3DS_INDEX_chesspawn and GL3DS_MATERIAL_chesspawn are not initialized, only GL3DS_VERTEX_chesspawn is readed in the file. So it cannot work until these data are initialized, GL3DS_INDEX_chesspawn above all !

If you want that read 3D (or 2D) models, try to convert it to OBJ file (very easy to read) and read it by yourself with a function.

If you don't want to make a read models function but have something powerful, you may be interest by [Assimp](http://www.assimp.org/) . This is a library that can read a lot of model format, whose 3DS, OBJ and even BLEND.

Comment: I have solve this question.Just set a larger number for the glTranslate func.3KU

Answer (score 0):

I Solve this question.Just set a larger number for glTranslatef.

```
glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -200.0);
```